# Resize image while generating watermark PHP GDLib

Tags: php, css, image-gallery

im writing a script to get an image gallery

i already have a folder of images, some portrait, some landscape.

and this script is run in a foreach loop to generate a gallery of images.

i can create an image of the exact same size and my watermark overlaid with this code

```
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);

$font = $font_path;
$size = 25;

$data = getimagesize($path);
$width = $data[0];
$height = $data[1];

// watermark positioning

if($width > $height){

  $width = $width / 8;

  $width = $width * 2;

  } else {

  $width = $width / 8;

  $width = $width * 1.2;

  }

$height = $height / 8;

$height = $height * 4.35;

// end watermark positioning


$temp_file = rand(100000000, 999999999).'.jpg';

# calculate maximum height of a character 
$bbox = imagettfbbox($size, 0, $font, 'ky');
$x = 8; $y = 8 - $bbox[5];
$x = $x + $width;
$y = $y + $height;


$text = 'WATERMARK TEXT';
shadow_text($im, $size, $x, $y, $font, $text);

imagejpeg($im, $temp_dir.'/'.$temp_file, 90);
```

this code works perfectly, but each image is saved as the original size (generally huge - which would waste bandwidth, as i ony need the images generated by gdlib to be small)

my problem is that some are landscape and some are portrait.

the images should be square, with black horizontal borders top and bottom if its a landscape picture, and black vertical borders left and right, if its a portrait

i would like a div for each image, an inside the div, an image (200 x 200px) and the album name underneath it.

i can make the divs with the images in, stay on one line with

```
style="display: inline;"
```

but, as soon as i add any text in the divs, they jump to one line per image.

this could be made more difficult as im using custom php/html in a joomla template, so the css is already designed.

any suggestions as to how i would go about this?

i basically want it to look something along the lines of ebays 'gallery view' when you search....

thanks guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use imagecopyresampled to rescale the image to obtain a thumbnail.

When you resize the image, you can detect landscape/portrait and add top+bottom bands or left+right bands, or just keep the image center as thumbnail.

Save the original image in a place and create thumbnail in another place to have them ready.